# Haskell - Continuing to next do after validating with either

Tags: validation, haskell, scope, either

I'm new to Haskell and using do notation to validate a user's choice with an Either.

```
userChoice :: String -> Either String String
userChoice option
    | option == "1" = Right "You proceed with option 1."
    | option == "2" = Right "You proceed with option 2"
    | option == "3" = Right "You proceed with option 3"
    | option == "4" = Right "You proceed with option 4"
    | otherwise = Left $ "\n\nInvalid Option...\nWhat would you like to do?\n" ++ displayOptions(0)

displayOptions :: Int -> String
displayOptions option
    | option == 0 = "1 - Option 1\n2 - Option 2\n3 - Option 3\n4 - Option 4"
    | otherwise = "invalid"

main = do
    putStrLn "Welcome."
    let start startMessage = do
        putStrLn startMessage
        let ask message = do
            putStrLn message
            choice <- getLine
            either ask ask $ userChoice(choice)
        ask $ "What would you like to do?\n" ++ displayOptions(0)
    start "Choose a number between 1-4."
```

This works fine, but after the user chooses a correct option, I'd like to proceed to the next part of the program. I could use return but I lose which option the user chose.

As an example, I can put return here when the user chooses a right, but then it will not say the String "You proceed with option...".

```
main = do
    putStrLn "Welcome."
    let start startMessage = do
        putStrLn startMessage
        let ask message = do
            putStrLn message
            choice <- getLine
            either ask return $ userChoice(choice)
        ask $ "What would you like to do?\n" ++ displayOptions(0)
    start "Choose a number between 1-4."

    -- putStrLn userChoice2(choice)

    let continue continueMessage = do
        putStrLn continueMessage
        let ask message = do
            putStrLn message
            choice <- getLine
            either continue continue $ userChoice(choice)
        ask $ "What would you like to do?"
    continue "We are now here..."
```

If I try to put continue as the right option then it throws a scope error.  Similarly, if I use return and try to make a primitive clone function for userChoice I no longer have access to the scope choice is in.

```
userChoice2 :: String -> String
userChoice2 option
    | option == "1" = "You proceed with option 1."
    | option == "2" = "You proceed with option 2"
    | option == "3" = "You proceed with option 3"
    | option == "4" = "You proceed with option 4"
    | otherwise = "\n\nInvalid Option...\nWhat would you like to do?\n" ++ displayOptions(0)
```

Is there a way to chain these together elegantly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to bind the value returned in the monad from `start`, like this:

```
main = do
    putStrLn "Welcome."
    let start startMessage = do
        putStrLn startMessage
        let ask message = do
            putStrLn message
            choice <- getLine
            either ask return $ userChoice(choice)
        ask $ "What would you like to do?\n" ++ displayOptions(0)

    -- THE NEW BIT I ADDED:
    opt <- start "Choose a number between 1-4."
    putStrLn opt   -- THIS PRINTS "You proceed with ..."

    -- SNIP
```

You can read about "desugaring `do` notation" to learn how this translates to lambdas and the methods of the `Monad` class (`>>=` and `return`).

---

A couple other suggestions:

You can use (and should prefer) pattern matching instead of guards and `==` (a method of the `Eq` class, which not all types implement). E.g.

```
userChoice2 option = case option of
    "1" -> "You proceed with option 1."
    "2" -> "You proceed with option 2"
```

Remember that in haskell the syntax for calling `foo` on `a` and `b` is `foo a b` not `foo(a,b)`

It can be very helpful to turn on warnings (both when you're learning and on production code bases) e.g. here I load your file in ghci after turning on `-Wall`:

```
Prelude> :set -Wall
Prelude> :l k.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( k.hs, interpreted )

k.hs:15:1: warning: [-Wmissing-signatures]
    Top-level binding with no type signature: main :: IO b
   |
15 | main = do
   | ^^^^

k.hs:24:5: warning: [-Wunused-do-bind]
    A do-notation statement discarded a result of type ‘String’
    Suppress this warning by saying
      ‘_ <- start "Choose a number between 1-4."’
   |
24 |     start "Choose a number between 1-4."
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Ok, one module loaded.
```

Notice it warns you that `start` returns `IO String` but that you've done nothing with the `String` value, which indeed was an error. If you really want to discard the value you can use `void` to make it explicit and silence the error.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was very thoughtful and informing, I appreciate it a lot.